# Javascript new Date() returns different date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I did create a date object out of '31/12/2018':

```
new Date('2018', '12', '31')
```

It does however create something completely different that I would expect.

```
Date {Thu Jan 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)}
```

What's happening?

Comment: MDN provides a pretty good Javascript reference, including [information about the `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 3):

Months are indexed starting from `0`. Use `11` for December, not `12` :

```
new Date(2018, 11, 31)
```

(and yes, there should be numbers instead of strings, which makes it a little less confusing)

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :

> **month**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

Answer (score 1):

Months start with 0 in JavaScript. January is `0`; December is `11`. `12` represents January the following year. You'll want to use `11` instead of `12`:

```
new Date('2018', '11', '31')
```

```
-> Mon Dec 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forget that months in JS starts with **0** instead 1.

Please use

```
new Date('2018', '11', '31')
```

in your case.